# How to list declared temporary tables in DB2

Tags: db2, temp-tables

You can created session temporary tables in DB2 using the [`DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/topic/com.ibm.db2z9.doc.sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_declareglobaltemptable.htm) statement. Is there any way to list all the tables that currently exist in the session's `SESSION` schema? Note *declared* global temporary tables do not exist in `SYSIBM.SYSTABLES`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer (as far as I know) is no.  Declared Global Temporary Tables (DGTT) do not show up in the catalogs (as you mentioned).

[Created Global Temporary Tables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/sqlref/src/tpc/db2z_sql_createglobaltemptable.html) do, but they are slightly different (have a look at [this other Stack Overflow answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15704745/458501) for differences).

If you simply need to know if the table exists or not (for example, if you're trying to create the DGTT later in an application), you could use a [`CONTINUE HANDLER`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPEK_12.0.0/apsg/src/tpc/db2z_handlerssqlproc.htm):

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR SQLSTATE '42710' SET DGTT_FOUND=1;
```

Depending on your platform, the `SQLSTATE` keyword may be optional.

Comment: your link is broken

Comment: @Hogan, I updated the links, but it appears that the article I referenced is now behind a paywall. I updated it to another Stack Overflow answer of mine that has most of the same information (and another source).

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread; I was looking for this too and found the following query helped:

```
db2 "select substr(tabname, 1, 20) tabname,
     substr(tabschema,1,10) tabschema, 
     temptabtype,
     tab_organization,
     substr(tbspace,1,12)tbspace
     from 
       table (sysproc.admin_get_temp_tables(sysproc.mon_get_application_handle(),'','')) gtt,
       syscat.tablespaces tbspace where (tabname = 'TEMP_T1' ) 
       and
       gtt.tbsp_id = tbspace.tbspaceid"
```

Result:

```
TABNAME              TABSCHEMA  TEMPTABTYPE TAB_ORGANIZATION TBSPACE     
-------------------- ---------- ----------- ---------------- ------------
TEMP_T1              SESSION    D           C                SYSTOOLSTMPS

  1 record(s) selected.
```

Note that this may be dependant on the Db2 version.
This info will only be valid in your session.