# DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE Vs CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE in DB2

Tags: performance, stored-procedures, db2, temp-tables

am creating a `GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` in DB2. and when i surfed i got a two way to create 
1. Declare 
2. Create.

```
1. DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE SESSION.TEMP_EMP
      (EMPNO  CHAR(6) NOT NULL,
       SALARY DECIMAL(9, 2),
       BONUS  DECIMAL(9, 2),
       COMM   DECIMAL(9, 2)) WITH REPLACE ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;

2. CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TMPDEPT
      (TMPDEPTNO   CHAR(3)      NOT NULL,
       TMPDEPTNAME VARCHAR(36)  NOT NULL,
       TMPMGRNO    CHAR(6),
       TMPLOCATION CHAR(16) ) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS ;
```

and from IBM site i got a info that create is the best since its being persistent , allowing all user sessions to access the same table definition without having to declare it at startup and many more advantages.

Link : http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0912globaltemptable/

and i had few queries in using create over declare:

1. I couldn't find the `Replace` keyword while using `CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` .
2. consider one scenario, 
   am opening a connection and executing a Stored Procedure,
   within that Stored Procedure am creating Global temp table 
   and with in that Stored Procedure am calling Another Stored Procedure 
   which again have `same` Create Temp table statement .. what will happen in this case.. 
   does it throw any error since both table naes are same and within the single connection?
3. Declare have session and create doesn't have?? does this related to persistant??
4. in performace wise which is better? Declare temp or create temp?
5. Suggest some scenarioes for the best usage of declare / create !!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [good article from Craig S. Mullins](https://www.craigsmullins.com/dbu_0802.htm) that covers the major differences between the two. For most purposes, they work the same.

Created Temp Tables are created in `DSNDB07`, which is the working file database (the same storage area used during SQL statements that need working storage). Declared Temp Tables are stored in temporary tablespace that you have to create.

There are some cons for CTT's:

> - Because they are not persistent, some typical database operations
>   including locking, logging, and recovery do not apply to created
>   temporary tables.
> - Indexes can not be created on created temporary tables so all access
>   is by a complete table scan.
> - Constraints can not be created on created temporary tables.
> - A null is the only default value permitted for columns of a created
>   temporary table.
> - Created temporary tables can not be referenced by DB2 utilities.
> - Created temporary tables can not be specified as the object of an
>   UPDATE statement.
> - When deleting from a created temporary table, all rows must be
>   deleted.
> - Although views can be created on created temporary tables, the WITH
>   CHECK OPTION can not be specified.

DTT are usually much more flexible:

> - Declared temporary tables can have indexes and CHECK constraints
>   defined on them.
> - You can issue UPDATE statements and positioned DELETE statements
>   against a declared temporary table.
> - You can implicitly define the columns of a declared temporary table
>   and use the result table from a SELECT.

Now for your numbered questions:

1.  & 2. There isn't one. I believe (and I'm not 100% sure if this is accurate, our shop
pretty much uses DTTs in all cases) that a CTT is declared once (by
a DBA), and then the application programmers can use it in any session.
Each connection will have their own copy, and once the application disconnects,
the data stored in that CTT in that session will go away.

3. `SESSION` is just the schema identifier for DTTs. It shows that it is a temporary
table that does not persist.

4. I think both will have about the same performance. They will be faster
than normal tables, because locking, logging, recovery, etc will not apply.

5. In general, I would say that DTTs are the way to go, but CTTs are
useful (as Craig says in his article):

> (CTTs) should be considered primarily when no updating of temporary data
> is needed and access to the temporary data is purely sequential.

Answer (score 1):

Craig S. Mullins article applies to DB2 for OS/390 platform.
In DB2 9.7 you actually can create indexes for both DGTT and CGTT. Also you can enable logging in CGTT. 
For 9.7 read here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.dbobj.doc/doc/r0054491.html

Answer (score 0):

4. We've found that Created Temp Tables have -- in our case -- performed far better than DTTs. It may be an exception (it depends), but the impetus for the change was seeing the number of Incremental Binds that were being performed with DTTs. Each transaction needed 23 temp tables. We ran a parallel test and found CTTs resulted in huge drops in both cpu and In_DB2 time. We also saw drops in lock/latch waits and found that with CTTs our ZIIP cpu began exceeding our GP cpu, which makes everybody happy.

We did not need DTT indexes or update access and had no use for any RI.